# When are property-based values resolved?

Tags: wix

I have a wix install file defined with a Property, IniFile inside a Component, and a custom dialog with a RadioButtonGroup that changes the value of said property.  The property is used as a value for one of the IniFile's entries.  Problem is it seems that IniFile value gets resolved prior to the property getting set via the radio buttons, as I always get the property's default value in my ini file.  So my question is - how do I get it to resolve the IniFile's value (a property) later, after it's been altered.

Here's a rough outline of what I have:

```
<Property Id="SlpStatic" Value="STATIC" />
.
.
<Component Id="UpdateSlpStatic" Guid="aa8867b4-129c-42f3-85cc-06b588c29a40" Directory="TARGETDIR">
   <CreateFolder />
   <IniFile Id="IniSlpStatic" Action="addLine" Section="Overrides" Name="config.ini" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Key="type" Value="[SlpStatic]" />
</Component>
.
.
<Control Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="SlpStatic" Id="SlpStaticChoice" Width="200" Height="42" X="112" Y="68">
   <RadioButtonGroup Property="SlpStatic">
       <RadioButton Text="SLP" Height="17" Value="SLP" Width="300" X="0" Y="0" />
       <RadioButton Text="Static" Height="17" Value="STATIC" Width="200" X="0" Y="25" />
   </RadioButtonGroup>
</Control>
```

I know that the SlpStatic property is getting set properly (I have another control that enables/disables based on its value), so the problem is that IniFile's value is getting resolved too early.

Comment: Nevermind!  Found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247017/wix-property-change-in-dialog-is-ignored-during-installation?rq=1